# same dayofweek for a given year in delphi

Tags: date, delphi

I'm using Delphi 11 with the new DateUtils library but i'm not able to get a date of same day in the past, for a given number of years.
i must retirn the same day of week for a given date of n years ago. so if today is sunday i must return the same sunday of n years ago.
i added the complete source of a real test application written in delphi with a bug fixed

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ComCtrls, system.DateUtils, system.Types;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    dtDataOggi: TDateTimePicker;
    Label1: TLabel;
    edYears: TEdit;
    bnCalcola: TButton;
    procedure bnCalcolaClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    function annobisestile(value : tDate) : integer;
  end;


var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}


procedure TForm1.bnCalcolaClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   DataAppoggio : tDate;
   NumberOfYearToSubtract : integer;
   annobis : integer; // is leap year?
   annoappoggio : integer;
   giorno : boolean;
   febb28 :tDate;
   i : integer;
begin
   DataAppoggio := dtDataOggi.date;
   NumberOfYearToSubtract := strToInt(edYears.Text);
   annobis := 0;
   annoappoggio := yearOf(DataAppoggio);
   febb28 := encodedate(annoappoggio ,2,28);

  if CompareDate(febb28,DataAppoggio) = GreaterThanValue then
     Giorno := true
  else
     Giorno := false;

     DataAppoggio := IncYear(DataAppoggio, -NumberOfYearToSubtract);
     // check if adataappoggio is before feb 28  so i must add a day
     if giorno then  begin
        for I := 0 to NumberOfYearToSubtract  do begin
           //annobiststile is a custom functions that returns 1 if the given year is a leap year
           annobis := annobis + annobisestile(encodeDate(annoappoggio,01,01));
           annoappoggio := annoappoggio -1;
        end;
     end
     else begin
        for I := 0 to NumberOfYearToSubtract -1  do begin
           annobis := annobis + annobisestile(encodeDate(annoappoggio,01,01));
           annoappoggio := annoappoggio -1;
        end;
     end;
     label1.Caption  :=  incDay(DataAppoggio, NumberOfYearToSubtract+annobis).ToString;
 end;

 function TForm1.annobisestile(value: tDate): integer;
begin
   if IsInLeapYear(value) then
      result := 1
   else
      result := 0;
end;
```

this functions return the exact day of a given numbers of past years but if this years are 3 or more, it does not mattch the same WeekOfTheYear.
any idea? thank you.

Comment: Can you make a function where the input is known and the result is presented and what is wrong?

Comment: Of course this is just a small real app, if a give '2022-02-25'  and past 3 years it returns '2019-03-01' instead of '2019-02-22'

Comment: Oooh! I thought 2022-02-25 minus 3 years is 2019-02-25. Would you mind explain why it should be 2019-02-22?

Comment: "*... with the new DateUtils library ...*" - `DateUtils` is actually not new, it has been around for a very long time.  In any case, why are you adjusting the days of the result based on the number of leap years subtracted? You should not need to do that, I would expect `IncYear()` to handle that for you. What happens if you just do this? `NumberOfYearToSubtract := StrToInt(edYears.Text); DataAppoggio := IncYear(dtDataOggi.Date, -NumberOfYearToSubtract); Label1.Caption := DataAppoggio.ToString;` What is the result compared to your input?

Comment: *I must return the **same day of week** for a given date of n years ago*. So, since a year is 365 days (366 on a leap year), the weekdays never coincide. Is it ok for you to calculate 52 weeks (52 * 7 = 364) back for every year? The weekday will be the same but the date will creep forward with 1.25 days for each year going backward in time. Today, 25.2.2022 is a Friday, 26.2.2021 was a Friday, 28.2.2020 was a Friday, 1.3.2019 was a Friday, 2.3.2018 was a Friday and so on. If this is ok for you then just take `TDate` of today and subtract n * 364, where n is number of years.

Comment: Btw. **just of curiosity**, what is the application (the purpose) of this need to have the same weekday but n years ago?

Comment: Sounds like a homework task to check the student's understanding of date arithmetic and  in which way it could be solved by code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is straight forward if you need the date of **same week number** and **same day of the week** `n` years before (or later). The `System.DateUtils` unit has all necessary functions.

First use functions `YearOf()`, `WeekOf()` and `DayOfTheWeek()` to get `InputYear`, `InputWeek` and `InputDOW` (day-of-week) from the `InputDate`.

Then use the `EncodeDateWeek()` function to convert `InputYear` + `YearsToAdd`, `InputWeek`, `InputDOW` to a `TDateTime`;

A complete sample code follows:

```
procedure TForm2.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  InputDate: TDate;
  InputYear: word;
  InputWeek: word;
  InputDOW:  word;
  YearsToAdd: integer;
  NewDate: TDate;
begin
  InputDate := dtDataOggi.date;
  InputYear := YearOf(InputDate);
  InputWeek := WeekOf(InputDate);
  InputDOW  := DayOfTheWeek(InputDate); // ISO 8601 Monday is first dow,
                                        // use DayOfWeek() for Sunday as first dow
  YearsToAdd := strToInt(edYears.Text); // use '-' in input for subtraction

  NewDate := EncodeDateWeek(InputYear + YearsToAdd, InputWeek, InputDOW);

  Memo1.Lines.Add(DateToStr(InputDate));
  Memo1.Lines.Add(DateToStr(NewDate));
end;
```

Edit:

You can shorten the code by removing the intermediate variables `InputYear`, `InputWeek` and `InputDOW` and move the calls to `YearOf(InputDate)`, `WeekOf(InputDate)` and `DayOfTheWeek(InputDate)` as parameters to `EncodeDateWeek()`.

```
procedure TForm2.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  InputDate: TDate;
  YearsToAdd: integer;
  NewDate: TDate;
begin
  InputDate := dtDataOggi.date;
  YearsToAdd := strToInt(edYears.Text); // use '-' in input for subtraction

  NewDate := EncodeDateWeek(
    YearOf(InputDate) + YearsToAdd, 
    WeekOf(InputDate), 
    DayOfTheWeek(InputDate));           // ISO 8601, monday is first dow
                                        // use DayOfWeek() for sunday as first dow
  Label1.Caption := DateToStr(NewDate);
end;
```

Comment: The `DateUtils` unit is available in both: [Delphi](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.DateUtils) and [Lazarus](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/dateutils/index-5.html) - one "just" has to read the docs which functions exist.

Comment: this solve the problem with the exact number of week from the beginnin of the year i have only changed the YearsToAdd in integer to have negative values because it results in a runtime `"range check error"`

Comment: Yes! Franz. You are right, thanks for the heads up. Corrected.

Comment: If I'm not completely wrong this code will fail on certain combinations because most years have 52 weeks but some will have 53 weeks. So you will have to handle this case separately.
Also the first days of the year (up to three days) may return the last week of the previous year for WeekOf(). So you might end up at the end of a year while your input was at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

You're overcomplicating things.  You don't need `function annobisestile` and you can replace `TForm1.bnCalcolaClick` with the following method.
In a nutshell, this subtracts the specified number of years, then adjusts the date by the number of days that it's off the original day of the week.

(This was done with 10.4, which doesn't have the new TDateTime helpers, so I've used `DateToStr()` instead of `.toString`.)

```
procedure TForm1.bnCalcolaClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   DataAppoggio : tDate;
   NumberOfYearToSubtract : integer;
   DOW : Integer;
begin
   DataAppoggio := dtDataOggi.date;
   NumberOfYearToSubtract := strToInt(edYears.Text);
   DOW := DayOfWeek(DataAppoggio);

   DataAppoggio := IncYear(DataAppoggio,-NumberOfYearToSubtract);
   DataAppoggio := IncDay(DataAppoggio,DOW-DayOfWeek(DataAppoggio));
   label1.Caption  :=  DateToStr(DataAppoggio);
end;
```